# Can you modify a column in document library without checking out the file using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, csom

I recently found out that you can edit a column in a document library without checking out the document using CSOM, but is that behavior really expected or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

What's your library version settings?

Here is my test result.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have the same settings as yours, but instead of using .update() I used UpdateOverwriteVersion()

Comment: also working with powershell

Comment: Test with UpdateOverwriteVersion, need check out also, you may test in a different library.

Comment: Hi forgot to tell that I deployed a Remote Event Receiver to the library, now I can not update it with powershell but the event receiver can still edit the column

Comment: How would you able to debug your solution?